# Rails associations has_many and belongs_to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations, model-associations

> ArgumentError in ProposalsController#index
>
> No association found for name `clients'. Has it been defined yet?

This error I get on my app. Can't find a solution to fix it. Any ideas?

Here is modals:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
   
  has_many :documents
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  
end
```

and

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  
  belongs_to :client
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  
  validates :name, presence: true 
end
```

Here is controller for Documents:

```
  def index
    if current_user.admin?
      @documents = Document.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20) 
    else
      @documents = Document.where("user_id = ?", current_user).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    end
  end
```

1. I have put "client_id" in db for Documents.
2. I have put all safe params in both controllers.

Comment: Could you include your code from `ProposalsController#index`? Note that from your definition here, you can call `document.client`, but not `document.clients`

Comment: @Julie just added. But if try /documents/new error is not ProposalsController#new. It happens for every method in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just missed a small detail. Always follow what the interpreter / compiler says and you can find what went wrong.

In your case `:clients` should be singular in the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` since it is a belongs_to

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail

  belongs_to :client

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  validates :name, presence: true 
end
```